# Can't draw links by node property using D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise

I'm trying to make a force layout on D3 for network visualization with nodes and links. I've been using v3 a little bit, but I switched to v5 in order to be able to link nodes using node attributes instead of node indexes (which required additional steps in d3 v3).

I got this code

https://jsfiddle.net/lioneluranl/4fxpp2co/1/

```
var linkpath = ("links.csv");
var nodepath = ("nodes.csv");
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var width = svg.attr("width");
var height = svg.attr("height");
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation();   

var nodes = [];
var links = [];

d3.csv(nodepath, function(d){
  node = {
    id: d.node,
    group: d.group,
    node: d.node
  };  

  nodes.push(node);

  d3.csv(linkpath, function(d){
    link = {
      source: d.source,
      target: d.target,
      type: d.type
    }; 

    links.push(link);

  });

}).then( function() {

  //console.log(links);
  //console.log(nodes);

  simulation
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { /*console.log(d);*/ return d.id; }))
      .nodes(nodes)      
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(10))
      .force("r", d3.forceRadial(function(d) { 
        if(d.group === "compound"){          
          return 240;
        } else { return d.group === "annotation" ? 0 : 100; }}))      

  // Create the link lines.
  var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 4)
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; });

  // Create the node circles.
 var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 8)
      .attr("class", function (d){ 

        return d.group;

      });

 simulation.on("tick", ticked);
 simulation.force("link").links(links);

function ticked() {
  node
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}


});
```

Which has been adapted from this

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/cd98bf52e9067e26945edd95e8cf6ef9

I have no problems drawing the nodes, but I'm unable to draw the links. Related documentation indicates that, as I think I'm doing, node attributes must be passed to links on force simulation, but I get this error:

`TypeError: can't assign to property "vx" on "PF05257": not an object`

Also, when doing this, the nodes won't behave as expected on the layout (the radial forces set won't work, see pictures attached), suggesting this link-by-node-attribute is messing with my simulation.

[image: Not broken layout, but without adding the forceLinks]
[image: Layout broken after trying to add links]

CSVs contain the following data:

nodes.csv:

```
node,group
C236103,compound
C327961,compound
C337527,compound
C376038,compound
C543486,compound
T24871,target
T27222,target
T33516,target
T33937,target
OG5_135897,annotation
PF01529,annotation
PF05257,annotation
PF11669,annotation
...
```

links.csv

```
source,target,type
T24871,PF05257,annotation
T27222,PF05257,annotation
T33516,PF01529,annotation
T33516,PF05257,annotation
T33516,PF11669,annotation
T33937,PF05257,annotation
T24871,C561727,bioactivity
T24871,C337527,bioactivity
T24871,C585910,bioactivity
...
```

Just for reference and data integrity sanity check, I got this working on d3 v3.
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a constructive criticism: indent your code properly<sup>1</sup>.

The first time I read it I missed the problem, because of the incorrect indentation. But then, with the correct indentation, the issue is clear, have a look at this:

```
d3.csv(nodepath, function(d) {
    node = {
        id: d.node,
        group: d.group,
        node: d.node
    };

    nodes.push(node);

    d3.csv(linkpath, function(d) {
        link = {
            source: d.source,
            target: d.target,
            type: d.type
        };

        links.push(link);

    });
})
```

You cannot nest `d3.csv` like this. The way your code is right now the second `d3.csv` is part of the row function of the first `d3.csv`, and that obviously won't work.

The correct approach here would be nesting the promises (which is an anti-pattern for some) or, even better, using `Promise.all` (since there is no `d3.queue` in v5):

```
var promises = [d3.csv("nodes.csv"), d3.csv("links.csv")];

Promise.all(promises).then(function(data) {
    var links = data[1];
    var nodes = data[0];
    //rest of the code here
});
```

As an additional tip, you don't need to push the objects to arrays in the outer scope: just deal with the parameter inside `then`.

Also, you don't need the row function for both CSVs, since your row functions are not doing anything right now (besides duplicating `node` as `id` they are simply returning the same object that you would have without them).

Here is a bl.ocks with your code and data, using `Promise.all`:

https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/30cb90cc9eb4f239f59b323bbdfe4293/3049fc77b8461232b6b149f39066ec39e0d111c1

---

<sup>1</sup> Most text editors, like Sublime Text, have plugins for indentation. You can also find several good tools online, [like this one](https://www.danstools.com/javascript-beautify/) for instance.

Comment: Snap... thank you very much! I'll go ahead and test it. Sorry for de indentation issue. I used Jsfiddle beautify function but didn't really check if it was correctly indented.